# Android canvas enhance performance of drawing speed

Tags: android, canvas, android-custom-view, surfaceview, graphics2d

I am creating a finger paint touch mechanism, and I am looking for ways to increase and enhance the performance of the drawing (make it fast and responsive).

In android to draw using canvas we basically create a custom view, we extend the (View) class, and finally we override the most important method to draw and that is the (onDraw) method. We could visualize the usual code for drawing on canvas to be like that:

**Usual Drawing**

```
   public class UsualDraw extends View{

    //constructor (usually 3)

     //........

    //the onDraw function

     @override
     protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){

       //here we draw what ever we want   

     }



   }
```

**First Notice**

I noticed that others use another technique to draw on canvas, and that involves multi-threading, and instead of extending (View) they extend (SurfaceView). Could be like that:

```
       public class AnotherDraw extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

      //constructor (usually 3)

        //........

       //the onDraw function

        @override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){

       //here we draw what ever we want   

        }

        //in addition to 3 methods
          @override
        protected void surfaceChanged(......){

        //...  

        }
           @override
        protected void surfaceCreated(......){

        //here background thread starts.  

        }

            @override
        protected void surfaceDestroyed(......){

        //here back ground thread should stop.

        }      



        }
```

basically its a drawing on the background thread.

**Second Notice**

I noticed that while touch and drawing on the screen, there is missing points which means when you draw very fast then the screen won't keep up with your finger speed (so there is missing touch points or maybe ignored touch points).

**My question**

1) Why some documentation extend View and others extend SurfaceView? What should I use in my case for responsive drawing? Does it make any difference?

2) What should I do to make the screen keep up with very fast drawing, and make sure that every path is drawn?

Comment: what is slow when you use `Canvas#drawPath` inside `View#onDraw` method?

Comment: @pskink lets say just for example (that you want to write a signature) which is a fast task, then you will notice that touch points won't keep up with the drawing.

Comment: then use "historical" events (see `MotionEvent` documentation)

Comment: @pskink I checked it, I think it gives an array of the missed touch points? does that mean that I should loop through the missed touch points and join them with the path again? In this case if I am fitting a curve between touch points, then how do I make sure that the missed points will fit perfectly and continuously with the whole path (In other words after I drawn a curved path using cubicTo() and then after that I checked the missing TouchPoints how do I fit them continuously with the ALREADY DRAWN PATH)?

Comment: so whats your code using historical values?

Comment: I didnt use them yet I am asking?

Comment: just use `getHistorical[XY]` as if they were `get[XY]` methods

Comment: @pskink so I should check If Historical Events are found Real Time during (TOUCH_MOVE event) or after the touch has finished which means in (TOUCH_UP event)?

Comment: this is described in `MotionEvent` documentation - see section **Batching**

Comment: @pskink they said "first  consume the historical coordinates then consume the current coordinates". So my First concern should be the HistoricalEvents?

Comment: yes, if you want to get all the points

Comment: @pskink what about SurfaceView vs View which one should I extend, does multithreading help in my case?

Comment: so is it slow now using a custom `View`? did you do any speed measurements? where is the bottleneck?

Comment: @pskink I didnt do a speed measurement as I don't know how to do this, but I can say that its fine (not really slow) in the case of testing it. I am not an expert in graphics, but  I am  doing my best to learn.

Comment: @pskink I am trying to know what are the basic factors for a fast responsive canvas.